# TextBlock should have an input from code (xaml, c#)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, textblock

in an .XAML I wrote

```
<TextBlock> x words found </TextBlock>
```

and in my .cs I wrote something like this:

```
public int number(A a, B b) {
    […]
    return resultsCount;
}
```

I want x to be resultsCount in this case.
How do I link it so x becomes a number of resultsCount?

Comment: Your question is not complete, you want to show resultsCount place of "x words found "

Comment: yourTextblock.Text =  $"{number(a,b)} were found";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the simplest solution:**

You can set your `TextBlock`  like this:

```
<TextBlock >
    <Run x:Name="MyRun" Text="0"/> // place for the 'X' of your code
    <Run Text="words found"/>
</TextBlock>
```

and in the codebehind, you can change the `Text` of MyRun in your `int number(A a, B b)`
 method like this:

```
public int number(A a, B b)
{
    […]
    MyRun.Text = resultsCount.ToString();
    return resultsCount;

}
```

**Solution that involves data binding:**

in this case you should define a property that raises `PropertyChanged` event on change like this:

```
public class CodeBehind : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string simpleString;
    public string SimpleString
    {
        get{ return simpleString; }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SimpleString"));
            simpleString = value;
        }
    }
    public int number(A a, B b)
    {
        […]
        return resultsCount;

    }
}
```

and then simply bind the `Text` property of `MyRun` with this `SimpleString` Property:

```
<TextBlock >
    <Run x:Name="MyRun" Text="0"/>
    <Run Text="words found"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Whenever you need to update that "X", in code behind, just do this:

```
SimpleString = number(a,b).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `binding` mechanic.

For that you need to create a `ViewModel`, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

An example:

```
namespace TestBind
{
    public class ExampleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string counter;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public ExampleModel()
        {
            this.Counter = "0 words found";
        }

        public string Counter
        {
            get { return this.counter; }
            set
            {
                this.counter = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

When you have your model, you connect it to your page:

```
 <Page.DataContext>
        <local:ExampleModel/>
 </Page.DataContext>
```

Inside of your `TextBlock` you can now bind the content to the `Counter` property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Counter}"/>
```

Inside of your Page.xaml.cs you should create a member parameter with the viewmodel:

```
private ExampleModel exampleModel;

public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            // Do stuff
            exampleModel = this.DataContext as ExampleModel;
        }
```

Now you can update the text by calling:

```
exampleModel.Counter = "100 words found";
```

For a detail description about binding read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).